# Dictionary of types

Tags: python, types, dictionary

In Python, what is the more efficient way of using types as dictionary keys? Given a `classObject`, should I use `classObject.__name__` or the object itself directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since type names don't have to be unique across modules, you must use the type (`classObject`) itself.

Luckily, types will automatically have a non-trivial hash value:

```
>>> class A(object): pass
>>> class B(object): pass
>>> hash(A)
2579460
>>> hash(B)
2579600
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "more efficient". As @phihag pointed out, the class object itself hashes just as well as the `__name__` string, so they are equally fine dictionary keys from that perspective. Where they might differ depends on what you want to do with the keys. For example, if you ever want to programmatically instantiate the class corresponding to one of your dictionary keys, it is pretty straight forward to do:

```
class A(object): pass
mydict[A] = 'blah'

# ...

for t,v in mydict.iteritems():
    if v=='blah':
        o = t() # instantiate the class/key
```

This would be much trickier to do if the dict keys were `__name__` strings rather than actual class objects.

Edit: well, somewhat trickier. You'd have to do something like:

```
o = globals()[t]()
```

But as @phihag mentioned, it is possible for distinct classes to have the same `__name__`, and that could be a problem.

Comment: Also, it isn't terribly unlikely that such a data structure can contain classes not bound to a global name at all (dynamically generated, local, in another module, etc.).